# Sign in with Apple alert showing when trying to login with Google (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have social login in my app - and it gives options to login via Apple, Google and Facebook.
Sign in with Apple and Facebook work alright. But if I tap on the `Sign in with Google` button, the `Sign in with Apple` alert still shows up.

I can cancel the box and continue login with Google. But I don't understand why it shows up. Is it because my Apple id is a gmail id?

I am using `invertase/react-native-apple-authentication` for `Sign in with Apple`.

Thank you for any tips